# AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule messes up debugger when passing moduleName==fileName

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2012

I ran into a really weird issue today.

Try by yourself:

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var name = new AssemblyName { Name = "Test" };
        AssemblyBuilder assembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(name, AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave);
        assembly.DefineDynamicModule(name.Name, name.Name+".dll", false);

        // Everything is okay so far...
        Debugger.Break();

        name = new AssemblyName { Name = "Test.dll" };
        assembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(name, AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave);
        assembly.DefineDynamicModule(name.Name, name.Name, false);

        // look at your stacktrace window here...
        Debugger.Break();
    }
}
```

On the first breakpoint, everything seems ok.

However, here is what I get on the second one:

[image: unknown function]

All further stepping operation will show these `<Unknown function>` in stacktrace window, and any further evaluation in spy window will lead to an internal error of the debugger.

However, it seems to be a bug of the debugger, since the code itself behaves normally.

Does someone know about this issue?

Is it a bad practice to give assembly module the same name as the dll file ?

***EDIT*** Seems hard to reproduce...

Visual studio 2013 : v12.0.30723.00 Update 3

Framework .Net 4.5.50938

Comment: Can't reproduce. Vs2012, Windows 8, .Net 4.5.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel See my edit... My colleague cannot reproduce it either.

Comment: I seriously doubt anybody here can help you with this, beyond the obvious "if it hurts then don't do it".  Report this at connect.microsoft.com